# Why is ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier not mapping to 'sub'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

Using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Identity Server 4 I have the following controller:

```
[HttpGet("posts"), Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPosts() {

  var authenticated = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

  var claims = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims;

  var id = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

}
```

I get all the `claims` but `id` is null ...

I checked all values in `claims` and I have a 'sub' claim with value 1.

Why is ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier not mapping to 'sub'?

Comment: Try setting this: JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false; This is mostly to fix the fact the `sub` claim gets translated into the `nameidentifier` claim.

Comment: It didn't solve it ... id is still null.

Comment: It's a good question that's why I upvoted it (from -1 to 0 now) but your example is irrelavant to your question. If you see 'sub' in your claims, then FindFirstValue of "sub".

Answer (score 38):

1. To not let Microsoft Identity to override claim names you have to use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` just before the `app.UseAuthentication()` in the API startup.
2. Use direct "sub" claim instead of ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier e.g.
   `var id = this.User.FindFirstValue("sub");`

For further reference please see detailed discussion on it:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2968#issuecomment-510996164

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Make sure to check the answer from `@Dominion` suggesting the newer  `JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear()`

Answer (score 17):

[Nan Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751404/nan-yu)'s answer no longer works as of .NET 8 Preview 7. I think the idiomatic way to do it since then is to set `JwtBearerOptions.MapInboundClaims` to `false` in the call to `AuthenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer`.

```cs
            services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
                {
                    jwtBearerOptions.MapInboundClaims = false;
                });
```

Alternatively, in spirit of the old method, just change `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` to `JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`

See discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2230).

Comment: Thanks! Was VERY bizarre after updating to .NET 8 that suddenly `FindFirstValue` for `UserIdClaimType` was returning a username and not user ID.

Answer (score 15):

I assume in OIDC configuration you have clear the inbound claim type map on the Microsoft JWT token handler with :

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

You can then manually setting the claim type mapping for claim `sub`:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Add("sub", ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and is still null ... No idea what is going on ...

Comment: what if you delete this line : `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`

Comment: With calling Clear I get the error `'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: sub'`

Comment: try delete this line : `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` , and also this one `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Add("sub", ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` , delete both codes

Comment: Thanks a lot...ur code add NameIdentifier claim type  when DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear() fr some other issue

Answer (score 8):

The static string `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` has the following value: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`

So no wonder it can't be used to look up the value of the `sub` claim.

If you know that the `sub` claim contains the user id, you can just do the lookup simply with the `sub` string.

`ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` works for looking up the user id only in cases when the `ClaimsPrincipal` was created with the default inbound claim type mapping, which maps the `sub` claim to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`.

But even in such cases it's more appropriate to use `userManager.Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType`, because this is the actual value used in the original mapping (which defaults to `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, but can be customized).

*(But yes, this whole mapping is quite confusing, and there are a number of Github issues opened where even MS devs lament that this is an evil existing solely for legacy reasons.)*