# How to make ASP.NET Core not to convert my claim types in the JWT token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

My JWT token looks likes this:
[image]

As you can see, the claim types are `sub, name, family_name`.

However, when I provide this JWT token to my `ApiController`, the interpreted claims (From `HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims` property) are converted into equivalent claim types from `System.Securtity.Claims.ClaimTypes`:

[image]

Why ASP.NET Core does that? And how can I make it not do that?

Comment: What's the issue caused by this convertion behaviour?

Comment: This question seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998262/why-is-claimtypes-nameidentifier-not-mapping-to-sub but has the opposite question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework needs `System.Securtity.Claims.ClaimTypes` for it's own default behavior,for example ,Set `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` when authenticated

You may try the codes below to disable the mapping:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(op =>
{
    op.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

Here's another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998262/why-is-claimtypes-nameidentifier-not-mapping-to-sub) relate